# Cross-Origin Request Blocked in Firefox only! [OPTIONS : 403 Forbidden]

Tags: amazon-web-services, firefox, cors, http-headers

It's a CORS problem again
[*and I don't have much knowledge about CORS*].

**My environment :**

I have JSON file stored in Amazon S3 server, and reading this JSON file from my web application.

**My issue :**

I am getting this in FireFox only

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
> the remote resource at *server*. (Reason: CORS header
> ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing)

**Note :** I have configured *CORSRule* in the server [Amazon S3]; after that, Chrome and other browsers work properly, but Firefox gives this error.

*In Firefox Network tab [inspect element]:*

Status : 403

Method : OPTIONS

Cause : xhr

Type : xml

*Request Headers :*

```
Host: myWebApp.net
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0
Accept: text/plain, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: https://myWebApp.net/page.jsp
Connection: keep-alive
```

*Response Headers :*

```
Content-Length: 0
Date: Thu, 24 Nov 2016 07:27:30 GMT
Location: https://webApp.s3.amazonaws.com/file.json
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

I have looked around but didn't find any causes.
So I need your help.
As it works properly in the Chrome browser, the issue is in Firefox only.

Please describe step by step if possible [*I am new to these things*].

Answer (score 0):

Opps!
Finally got solution.

> The issue was in Amazon S3's ***CORSConfiguration***

I don't know much about it, but now its allowing Cross-Origin from all browsers.

I have changes *CORSConfiguration* as :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
 <CORSRule>
   <AllowedOrigin>https://myWebApp.net</AllowedOrigin>
   <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
   <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
   <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
   <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
  <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
  <ExposeHeader>x-amz-server-side-encryption</ExposeHeader>
  <ExposeHeader>x-amz-request-id</ExposeHeader>
  <ExposeHeader>x-amz-id-2</ExposeHeader>
 </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

by this rules, browsers getting proper ***Request Headers*** and ***Response Headers***.

**Request Headers :**

```
Host: myWebApp.s3.amazonaws.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Access-Control-Request-Headers: x-requested-with
origin: https://myWebApp.net
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
```

**Response Headers :**

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-requested-with
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://myWebApp.net
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3000
Content-Length: 0
Date: Thu, 24 Nov 2016 13:21:17 GMT
Server: AmazonS3
Vary: Origin, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-expose-headers: x-amz-server-side-encryption, x-amz-request-id, x-amz-id-2
x-amz-id-2: emYYMILNIdkCejpjuDXz4Haks87asdhj/7JL5AASt/8eIwKdgO1Gb/AzGRg7SU/GH55IVopScg=
x-amz-request-id: 307572CDFF39F443
```